# Adding php-curl in a Yocto build

Tags: php, curl, yocto, php-curl

I've been building a custom image using Yocto and wpewebkit to use within docker. I need to run a local web server with php, which I have accomplished no problem. I need to use curl within my project and I have apache2, php, modphp, and curl installed. All I need is php-curl but I cannot find how to install this. Does anyone know how or if I can do this? I've put in all my efforts on googling multiple phrases but I only find how to install php-curl using apt-get or yum, or I get links to the meta-* directories which I have access to within my build files anyways.

If it helps at all, this custom image was based on the image provided from the following project on GitHub: https://github.com/resin-io-playground/resin-wpe/tree/master/base-image . I already spoke to the developer and their knowledge of PHP is limited.

EDIT #1: Progress so far, had to update the curl.bb file to properly include libcurl-dev, and then worked with @pmod's suggestion to incorporate curl into the php build. Everything seemed to run okay until I received the following error:

```
| ../php-7.1.9/configure: line 386: test: please: integer expression expected
| configure: error: reinstall
| ../php-7.1.9/configure: line 275: return: please: numeric argument required
| ../php-7.1.9/configure: line 285: exit: please: numeric argument required
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /base-image/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/php-native/7.1.9-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: /base-image/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/php-native/7.1.9-r0/temp/run.do_configure.29590:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /base-image/build/tmp-glibc/work/x86_64-linux/php-native/7.1.9-r0/temp/log.do_configure.29590)
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/base-image/build/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.1.9.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
```

Edit #2: I've gone ahead and added everything I was missing. I'm getting the same error above, where the function do_configure during the php build is failing. I'm posting below what I ensured I have in my curl.bb file (I had to add this), what I have in my php.inc file, and the curl files located staging directory.

curl.bb:

```
PACKAGES =+ "lib${BPN} lib${BPN}-native lib${BPN}-dev lib${BPN}-dev-native"

FILES_lib${BPN} = "${libdir}/lib*.so.*"

FILES_lib${BPN}-dev = "${includedir} \
                       ${libdir}/lib*.so \
                       ${libdir}/lib*.a \
                       ${libdir}/lib*.la \
                       ${libdir}/pkgconfig \
                       ${datadir}/aclocal \
                       ${bindir}/*-config"
```

php.inc:

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append = " --with-curl=${libdir}/.."
DEPENDS_${PN} += "libcurl-dev libcurl-dev-native"
```

PHP Staging Directory:

```
/installeddeps/curl-native
/installeddeps/curl-native.b77f37db31cf2391919a12c5c9774bff
/installeddeps/curl-native.complete
/usr/share/aclocal/libcurl.m4
/usr/bin/curl-config
/usr/bin/crossscripts/curl-config
/usr/bin/curl
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/usr/lib/libcurl.so
/usr/lib/libcurl.a
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4
/usr/include/curl
/usr/include/curl/curl.h
/usr/include/curl/curlrules.h
/usr/include/curl/curlbuild.h
/usr/include/curl/curlver.h
/usr/include/curl/easy.h
```

Comment: If you're using docker, you can use `# docker-php-ext-install curl` in your Dockerfile or in your container once it is started (https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#how-to-install-more-php-extensions).

Comment: Have you tried creating recipe for php-curl? If so, show it to us together with your fauilure, otherwise, try to create one.

Comment: @Flo I gave that a shot and it didn't work. That would normally work except I'm using wpewebkit, and a majority of packages are not available within the image, including apt-get. All that has to be built within the image.

Comment: @Anders I am not sure how to create a recipe for php-curl. I would think Yocto should already have a recipe and I'm having difficulty finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php), PHP/cURL feature is enabled at php configuration stage with **--with-curl=[dir]** option.

I checked the main recipe include file [php.inc](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php.inc) and couldn't find such configuration option. So, try creating in your working layer **php_%.bbappend** file with (or add this directly to the bottom of **php.inc** to test):

```
EXTRA_OECONF_append_class-target = " --with-curl=${STAGING_LIBDIR}/.."
DEPENDS_append_class-target = " curl"
```

Note, that **curl** package among **DEPENDS** because it is needed at build stage.

I don't think you need to update curl recipe with PACKAGES and FILES, pkg_config should take care

Comment: I gave that a shot and this is what I got:

ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'libcurl-dev-native' (but virtual:native:/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.1.9.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)

Comment: I realized the curl.bb file did not include everything for libcurl-dev, so I added those in and tried again and got a different error: Task (virtual:native:/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/php/php_7.1.9.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'

Comment: @JulianV please try DEPENDS_ instead of RDEPENDS, because libcurl-dev is needed at build time. Also, I am not sure why you think curl.bb doesn't include everything, there should be curl-target.inc that contains what is needed

Comment: @JulianV if you still have configure error for php - it's good to look at the log, but most possibly it could be one of unsatisfied requirements from the first link: in staging dir there should be /usr/include/easy.h /usr/include/curl.h, /usr/lib/libcurl.a

Comment: Well based on the errors I got, it seemed that there were missing dependencies and I did find in curl.bb that the libcurl-dev package and all the .so and .a files were being excluded, which I properly re-included. At this point I believe that my main issue is with --with-curl=[dir]. I believe I need to find the correct directory location to point to and I should be okay.

Comment: @JulianV what is the version of curl recipe you are using? Can you find libcurl.a in staging dir at all?

Comment: I'm using version 7.54.1-r0. I ran the find command and these are the files in the php-native directory: ./build/libcurl | ./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/libcurl.m4 | ./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc | ./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libcurl.so
./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libcurl.a | ./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.4.0 | ./recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4

Comment: @JulianV I have updated my answer, I think STAGING_LIBDIR should be used instead of libdir and I added class-target to isolate this only for target build. Not sure why you have php-native - I do assume you are building php for target or .... ?

Comment: you were absolutely right. The image successfully built and I was able to use php-curl no problem! I was using php-native because the build was failing without it, but it was no longer required after changing to STAGING_LIBDIR. Thanks so much!